# What is the cellular automaton interpretation of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, cellular-automaton

Gerard 't Hooft has presented a new interpretation of quantum mechanics called: [Cellular Automaton](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1548)

Is there anyone who can give a summary of the main points of the interpretation and its main difference with other interpretations and if it can also go beyond interpretation and have physical conclusions?

Comment: Please include relevant references (e.g. arxiv link to 't Hooft  "The Cellular Automaton Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics" (2014), https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1405.1548 ).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600367/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4200/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19647/226902